# Update Large Number of rows in sql server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-update, query-performance, bulkupdate

I'm trying to update a column in a table which has ~90,000 rows. Is there is any optimized way to update the table?

I have added necessary indexes.. so that no table scans/lookups are not happening. But still it takes much time to run (1hr).

My scenario:

```
DECLARE @ParentID   NVARCHAR(100),
        @Con_ERID   INT

DECLARE @MaxCount   INT, 
        @MinCount   INT, 
        @Id         INT

SELECT @MaxCount = MAX(Id) from [dbo].[ParentIDStaging] where Type='grid'

SET @MinCount = 1

WHILE @MinCount <= @MaxCount 
BEGIN

SELECT @Id = ConID FROM [dbo].[ParentIDStaging] WHERE Id = @MinCount  and Type = 'grid'

IF @Id IS NOT NULL
BEGIN

SELECT  @Con_ERID   =   ErId    FROM Context (NOLOCK) Where ConId = @Id
SELECT  @ParentID   =   Identifier FROM Recording (NOLOCK) where ErId = @Con_ERID

    BEGIN TRAN

        UPDATE  [ParentIDStaging]       WITH (ROWLOCK)
        SET [ParentID]   = @ParentID
        WHERE   ContentType = 'grid'
        AND ConID   = @Id

    COMMIT
END

SET @MinCount = @MinCount + 1
END
```

Comment: It is because you are updating one record at a time and using explicit locks/transactions.

Comment: As others have said (and I'm going to repeat) looping, separate transactions, etc. are all going to slow you down.  I'm also curious if ParentIDStaging.ParentID is involved anywhere in the key of a `clustered index`.  If it is, every update is going to (almost certainly) cause cascades of updates in ParentIDStaging as the rows in the table (even if it's only one leaf node at a time) are rearranged.  If this is the case, you would be better off dropping and recreating the `clustered index` before/after your loop.

Comment: Again - I don't know your data/schema/process - but I'm also curious if ParentIDStaging.ParentID is always wrong (and needs updating).  I've seen loops like this before where they were updating all records in a table, when only a small number of new rows had the "wrong" value - and simply adding `and ParentID<>@ParentID` to the `where` had a profound effect on performance.

Comment: Hi.. ParentID contains NULL Values intially..im updating the parentid column with a value from other table.. this parentid column needs to be filled with the actual value(in the update stmt in the qry)
And there is no Clustered Index on the ParentIDStaging table..I have created only non-clustered indexes on the table so tat no table scan can happen...but still the performance is poor..

Comment: have you checked whether each `select` is covered? why are you breaking the update into separate transactions?  all of these will have an impact.  I would check the indexes (so each query/join is covered) and then look at a set based update - rather than loops.

Answer (score 2):

Looping is slow. Try doing it in one update with include the relevant other tables using joins. Your query can probably be writen like this (don't know your actual schema):

```
UPDATE PS
SET PS.ParentID = Recording.Identifier
FROM ParetnIDStaging PS
JOIN Context on (Context.ConId = PS.ConId)
JOIN Recording on (Recording.ErId = Context.ErId)
WHERE ...
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are looping and updating one record at a time and using explicit locks/transactions.

Without knowing your underlying structure - I would bet you could do what you are trying with an update from a select.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE ParentIDStaging    
SET parentIdStaging.ParentID=recording.Identifier
from ParentIDStaging   
join Context on context.ConId = ParentIDStaging.ConId
join recording on contect.erid=recording.erId
WHERE   parentIdStaging.ContentType = 'grid'
AND parentidStaging.Type='grid'
```